# How to retrieve the list of computer shutdown timing for Windows OS?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, shutdown

Is it possible to retrieve the list of shutdown timing (regardless if it is shut down by the computer or by the user) for a Windows OS XP and up via command prompt or software or anything?

For example, I open a command prompt then type `shutdowntiming`, it will list all the timing whereby the computer is either being power off / shut down by the user or by the computer itself and display something like the following:

```
=============================================================
| Date           | Time                  |  Shut Down Type  |
=============================================================
| 01 Jan 2012    | 19:00:00              |  User            |
=============================================================
| 02 Jan 2012    | 19:11:14              |  Computer        |
=============================================================
| 03 Jan 2012    | 17:01:01              |  User            |
=============================================================
```

Comment: if you want some power fun in windows 7 , check out the powercfg command in a command prompt.  try powercfg /?  for extensive help.

Comment: @Psycogeek, I believe that powercfg provide function such as shut down and start up. powercfg does not provide a list of shut down timing.

Comment: XP ahh.  the event viewer shows some stuff, but not as extensive and filterable as windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/disable-shutdown-event-tracker-windows-2003.html

Windows server 2003 does offer a `shutdown-tracker`. I have not attempted to use this on XP, but the article does talk about workstation mode.

I hope this helps steer you in the right direction.